# Aspose.words mailmerge. Text in table cell gets truncated if it overflows page

Tags: html, doc, mailmerge, aspose.words

I am executing mailmerge with regions. For that purpose I am using the following callback :

```
 void IFieldMergingCallback.FieldMerging(FieldMergingArgs e)
    {
        //html content of the comment
        if (e.FieldName == "Content")
        {
            DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(e.Document);
            builder.MoveToMergeField(e.DocumentFieldName);
            builder.InsertHtml((string)e.FieldValue);
        }
    }
```

The latter handles field, that assumes html content. However, if the content, overflows page length, it does not continue on another page, and simply gets truncated. How should I elaborate the callback to avoid that (or what settings I have to apply to document before executing mailmerge)? Is it somehow related to the fact, that I am using trial version of Aspose.Words ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the properties of table row. If "Allow row to page break" is checked, your table should automatically move to the next page. I also tested using the similar method as yours, it worked.

[image: Table properties]

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I already tried the latter. I just figured out, that when I am creating a table from within the code, rows break gracefully, but when I try to insert MergeField values using table from the template, I encounter this problem. Maybe there's something wrong with the template?! Can You please check it  (https://www.dropbox.com/s/auydebf5y60ihm0/Kommentaaride_koond_template--.docx?dl=0) ?

Comment: Just realized, that I had to specify these settings for data rows and header rows separately. Since it was done, works like a charm. On the contrary, before I figured it out, I tried to apply the setting to the whole table, and of course the result was a mess.